# Jsystem test unknown failure using Spirent Test Center

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jsystem

I have some weird problem and don't have a clue about how to solve it.
I run automation tests using the Spirent Test Center API on win slave (64 bit 8GB RAM).
As far as I know test center support only 32bit compilation therefore some of my prerequisites is to get 32Bit java from nexus to slave and point my JAVA_HOME to this directory.
when I start my test and get to the init function of TC I don't get any error and Jenkins skip all other stages and finish the job.
when I connect to the slave via RDP and disconnect the test run as it should.

this is the failure:

```
     11:20:07    [system] 
     11:20:07    [jsystem] 08:20:07: Initializing STC object (Chassis IP: XXXXXXX)
     [Pipeline] unit
     11:20:09  Recording test results
     11:20:09  No test report files were found. Configuration error?
     [Pipeline] }
     [Pipeline] // dir
     [Pipeline] }
     [Pipeline] // script
     [Pipeline] }
     [Pipeline] // withEnv
     [Pipeline] }
     [Pipeline] // stage
     [Pipeline] }
     [Pipeline] // ansiColor
     [Pipeline] }
     [Pipeline] // timestamps
     [Pipeline] }
     [Pipeline] // node
     [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
     ERROR: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
     Finished: FAILURE
```

```
and after connect and disconnect I get this:

<pre>
 [jsystem] 08:12:58: Initializing STC object (Chassis IP: XXXXX)
 11:13:37    [jsystem] STC init pass.
 11:13:37    [jsystem] 08:13:35: Init cli, host: XXXXX
 11:13:37    [jsystem] The supported auth Methods are:
 11:13:37    [jsystem] publickey
 11:13:37    [jsystem] gssapi-keyex
```

UPDATE:
I manage to find the error:

```
    11:54:58  An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
    11:54:58  #
    11:54:58  # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    11:54:58  #
    11:54:58  #  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x74ca5b9b, pid=4356, tid=0x00000ecc
    11:54:58  #
    11:54:58  # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
    11:54:58  # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode windows-x86 )
    11:54:58  # Problematic frame:
    11:54:59  # C  [ucrtbase.dll+0x25b9b]
```

I try to google it and play with the java heap size but it doesn't help.
I don't see any errors in the reports.
Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem occurred because I need that user should be login to the agent.
My solution was to set the following registry keys in order to assure this.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows

or by the script:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d domainname /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d Administrator /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d Pa$$w0rd /f
```